# Interest rate, probability of tuition

Tags: probability, finance, mathematical-modeling

A new government introduces tuition of 10.000 Euro/year, increasing
yearly with the inflation rate of 2%.  At the same time, a prospective
'perpetual student'  enrolls at the university.  She expects that with 10% probability the government fails after 1 year, with 80% probability it is voted out of office after 4 years, and with 10% probability after 8 years (when she is still studying).
In  all  these  cases  tuition  will  be  cancelled  immediately  by  the  new
government.   What  is  the  expectation  value  of  the  total  amount  of
tuition she has to pay?

Hello

My discrete probability space $M:=\{1,4,8\}$

$P(t)$..total tuition after t year

Expected value $E(P_F)= 0.1*P(1)+0.8*P(4)+0.1*P(8)$

$P(0)=10.000$

$P(1)=10.00(1+0.02)+10.000$

$P(2)=10.00(1+0.02)*(1+0.02)+P(1)=10.00(1+0.02)^2+10.00(1+0.02)+10.000$

$P(3)=10.00(1+0.02)^3+P(2)=10.000(1.02)^3+10.00(1+0.02)^2+10.00(1+0.02)+10.000$

$P(4)=10.000*\sum_{j=0}^4 (1+0.02)^j=10.000* \frac{1- 1.02^5}{1-1.02} $

$E(P_F)= 0.1* 2.02*10.000+0.8*10.000* \frac{1- 1.02^5}{1-1.02} + 0.1*10.000* \frac{1- 1.02^9}{1-1.02} $

Ist this correct?

Comment: In the case of what you are calling P(1), you pay the 10,00 at the start of the year. If after 1 year (that is, at the end of the first year), the government fails, you don't pay any more. Similarly, you need to adjust your calculations for P(4) and P(8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At year 1, Let T(1) be the Tuition and there is a probability that the government cancels the tuition in which case you would have paid only 10,000 at the start.

At year 4, Let T(4) be the Tuition and there is a probability that the government cancels the tuition in which case you would have paid

$$ \frac{1.02^4-1}{1.02-1}$$

In a similar argument T(8) would be

$$ \frac{1.02^8-1}{1.02-1}$$

Now compute $E(T) = 0.1*T(1) + 0.8*T(4) +0.1*T(8)$.

You are right except on the G.P forumla.

Good luck